# Why does Datepicker disable one day ahead?

Tags: reactjs, datepicker

I'm using the `DatepickerField` component i created. And there is a bug. I have an array called Holidays (i will just put a dummy date for now) and if this date is among the dates I listed, it should be disabled, but it disables 1 day later. Why is this happening?

```
<DatepickerField
              name="nextSalaryDate"
              datepickerProps={{
                minDate: nextSalaryDateMin,
                maxDate: nextSalaryDateMax(),
                disableDayFn: (date) => {
                  console.log([ "2023-12-26" ]?.includes(moment(date).format("YYYY-MM-DD")), moment(date).format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
                  return (date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6 || [ "2023-12-26" ]?.includes(moment(date).format("YYYY-MM-DD")));
                }
              }}
              validate={[ this.validators.required ]}
              fieldProps={{
                required: true
              }}
              inputProps={{}}
              label="Next Salary date"
              help="Pick a date"
              {...nextSalaryDate} />
```

```
false '2023-12-25'
true '2023-12-26'
false '2023-12-27'
false '2023-12-28'
false '2023-12-29'
false '2023-12-30
```

This is DatepickerField Component

```
//@ts-nocheck
import _ from "lodash";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import React, { Component, PureComponent, Fragment } from "react";
import reactDom from "react-dom";

import cx from "classnames";
import moment from "moment";
import Pikaday, { type PikadayOptions } from "pikaday";
import { Field, type BaseFieldProps } from "redux-form/dist/redux-form";

import {
  Form,
  Input,
  Popup,
  type InputProps,
  type FormFieldProps
} from "semantic-ui-react";

import { Icon, DateFormat } from "kit/ui";

import ValidationMessages from "./ValidationMessages";

import "pikaday/css/theme.css";
import "pikaday/css/triangle.css";
import "./DatepickerField.styles.scss";

class DatepickerField extends Component {
  static defaultProps = {
    inputFormat: "DD-MM-YYYY",
    stateFormat: "YYYY-MM-DD"
  };

  static getDerivedStateFromProps = (props, state) => {
    if (!props.input.value) {
      return {
        dateStr: ""
      };
    }
    if (props.input.value) {
      const activeDateStr = moment(props.input.value, props.stateFormat).format(
        props.inputFormat
      );
      return {
        dateStr: activeDateStr
      };
    }
    return state;
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.datePickerInstance = null;
    this.reRenderDatePicker = this.reRenderDatePicker.bind(this);
  }

  state = {
    dateStr: ""
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const { inputFormat, stateFormat } = this.props;

    this.datePickerInstance = new Pikaday({
      field: reactDom.findDOMNode(this.refs.pikaday),
      container: reactDom.findDOMNode(this.refs.pikadayContainer),
      // onSelect: this.props.input.onChange,
      // bound: false,
      position: "bottom left",
      format: "YYYY-MM-DD",
      firstDay: 1,
      defaultDate: _.get(this, "props.input.value", new Date()),
      keyboardInput: false,
      i18n: {
        previousMonth: "",
        nextMonth: "",
        months: moment.months(),
        weekdays: moment.weekdays(),
        weekdaysShort: moment.weekdaysShort()
      },
      ...this.props.datepickerProps,
      onSelect: (selectedDate) => {
        const dateArr = [
          selectedDate.getFullYear(),
          selectedDate.getMonth(),
          selectedDate.getDate()
        ];
        const inputValue = moment(dateArr).format(inputFormat);
        const stateValue = moment(dateArr).format(stateFormat);
        this.setState({
          dateStr: inputValue
        });
        this.props.input.onChange(stateValue);
        this.datePickerInstance.hide();
      }
    });
    if (this.props.input.value) {
      this.datePickerInstance.setDate(
        this.props.input.value ?
          moment(this.props.input.value, this.props.stateFormat).toDate() :
          "",
        true
      );
    }
    window.addEventListener("resize", _.throttle(this.reRenderDatePicker, 100));
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    const { datepickerProps: oldDatepickerProps = {} } = prevProps;
    const { datepickerProps = {} } = this.props;
    if (this.state.dateStr !== prevState.dateStr) {
      this.datePickerInstance.setDate(
        this.state.dateStr ?
          moment(this.state.dateStr, this.props.inputFormat).toDate() :
          "",
        true
      );
    }

    if (oldDatepickerProps.minDate !== datepickerProps.minDate) {
      this.datePickerInstance.setMinDate(datepickerProps.minDate);
    }
    if (oldDatepickerProps.maxDate !== datepickerProps.maxDate) {
      this.datePickerInstance.setMaxDate(datepickerProps.maxDate);
    }
    this.reRenderDatePicker();
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener("resize", this.reRenderDatePicker);
    this.datePickerInstance.destroy();
  }

  handleClearInput = () => {
    this.props.input.onChange("");
    this.setState({
      dateStr: ""
    });
  };

  reRenderDatePicker() {
    this.datePickerInstance.adjustPosition();
  }

  showAndTriggerRender = () => {
    _.invoke(this.datePickerInstance, "show");
    this.reRenderDatePicker();
  };

  render() {
    const {
      meta,
      input,
      help,
      label,
      fieldProps = {},
      inputProps = {},
      ...restProps
    } = this.props;

    const id = date-picker-${meta.form}-${restProps.id || input.name};

    return (
      <Form.Field
        className="field-holder field-input"
        error={meta.touched && !!meta.error}
        {...fieldProps}>
        {!!label && (
          <label htmlFor={id}>
            {label}
            {!_.isEmpty(input.value) && (
              <Popup
                inverted
                size="mini"
                position="left center"
                trigger={
                  <Icon
                    style={{ float: "right" }}
                    color="grey"
                    onClick={this.handleClearInput}
                    className="cursor-pointer"
                    name="times" />
                }
                content={<span>Clear date</span>} />
            )}
          </label>
        )}

        <Input
          ref="pikaday"
          autoComplete="off"
          readOnly
          id={id}
          icon="calendar"
          iconPosition="left"
          {...inputProps}
          value={this.state.dateStr}
          onClick={this.showAndTriggerRender} />

        <input
          className="hidden-input"
          type="text"
          tabIndex="-1000"
          {...input} />

        <div className="pikaday-container" ref="pikadayContainer" />

        {!!help && <p className="field-desc">{help}</p>}

        <ValidationMessages
          errorMessage={meta.error}
          isVisible={meta.touched && !!meta.error} />
      </Form.Field>
    );
  }
}

DatepickerField.propTypes = {
  meta: PropTypes.object,
  input: PropTypes.object,
  inputProps: PropTypes.object,
  fieldProps: PropTypes.object,
  validate: PropTypes.array,
  label: PropTypes.string,
  help: PropTypes.string,
  datepickerProps: PropTypes.object,
  inputFormat: PropTypes.string,
  stateFormat: PropTypes.string
};

type ComponentPropsType = {
  name: string;
  id: string;
  label: React.ReactNode | string;
  help: React.ReactNode | string;
  fieldProps: FormFieldProps;
  inputProps: InputProps & React.TextareaHTMLAttributes;
  datepickerProps: PikadayOptions;
};

// eslint-disable-next-line react/no-multi-comp
export default class FieldHoc extends Component<
  BaseFieldProps & ComponentPropsType
> {
  static Datepicker = DatepickerField;
  static DatePicker = DatepickerField;

  render() {
    return <Field component={DatepickerField} {...this.props} />;
  }
}

// export default DatepickerField;
```

Comment: This could be a timezone issue. Dates in JS always use UTC internally, but when converted to a string or when used as a source by Moment functions, your local browser timezone offset may get applied. I'm not sure when & where this happens (or when it does not) but I would recommend looking for a date/timezone correction with that in mind.